# Linux I2C driver porting issue

Tags: linux-device-driver, i2c

I am porting an I2C driver to Linux-4. This device provides multiple I2C addresses for different function simultaneously.

For example:

```
address 0xAA is for access of SPI flash. 
address 0xA0 is for access of EEPROM.  
address 0x60 is for normal access (control purpose).
```

Is it possible to support access of different I2C address in single-one I2C device driver?

Any help appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Dražen Grašovec and user2699113 's help.

I am porting a I2C device driver (chip, client) to Linux-4.9.
This chip accepts different I2C device address for different purpose.
My goal is to create only one I2C device on Linux device tree file (.dts)

I resolved my issue by using i2c_new_dummy().

In driver probe function,
I made two i2c_new_dummy() to create two additional i2c clients.
One(client#1) is for accessing of I2C address 0xAA, another(client#2) is for I2C address 0xA0.
So I can use client#1 to communicate with its SPI flash and use client#2 to access it EEPROM.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible. Using i2c_transfer() you are giving particular address in i2c_msg structure of the device you want to communicate with. So your driver will be able to communicate with all of the functions of your i2c device.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what type of I2C driver you are talking about, bus(adapter) or chip(client) driver?

`i2c-dev.c` is a kind of bus driver with character device interface which exports kernel low level I2C API to userspace.

For each registered I2C adapter Kernel will add `i2c-N` device node in `/dev`userspace interface.

But you can't read/write EEPROM chip attached to `/dev/i2c-N` like simple character device or file. You need to write some utility program regarding chip protocol.

But in Linux there is are special EEPROM chip drivers like `eeprom.c`  or `at24.c` for registering I2C EEPROM devices with addresses of 0x50..0x57(if I'm not wrong) to Kernel and  creating  files in `/sys` userspace interface.

You can access them as a file in:`/sys/bus/i2c/devices/0-005x/eeprom`